# HTTP Error when trying to upload images to WordPress

Tags: wordpress, image, file-upload, upload

I'm trying to upload simple images in WordPress - photos taken by DSLR camera. Every once in awhile I'll get just a little red box saying "HTTP Error" with no other explanation.

At first, I thought it's the file size as the images where larger than 10MB although I did notice that it would work for some images but not for others. Eventually I got stuck with a small collection of images that would not upload at all so I used Photoshop batch converter and reduced their size to about 1-2MBs. However, they still do not upload properly. I then tried to open and resave them with Paint, I also changed the extension from .jpg to .png but nothing works!

It is very frustrating that something as simple as image upload in WordPress does not work (always). Anyone with a suggestion how to fix this problem or at least narrow it down and find out what's causing it?

Comment: please put your upload code here

Comment: There is no upload code - I'm using the default media feature in WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

if you try every solution out there for htaccess and it wont work , you may have imagick installed as your default lib for your php in the server 
for a fix use this in your `functions.php` file.

```
add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', 'change_graphic_lib' );

function change_graphic_lib($array) {
  return array( 'WP_Image_Editor_GD', 'WP_Image_Editor_Imagick' );
}
```